# Affecting skill gain amount in module based on color

Tags: azerothcore

My goal is to increase skill gain for orange crafting recipes only. Thus far I have successfully managed to modify the core code as such:

```cpp
// in PlayerUpdates.cpp, UpdateGatherSkill, after gathering_skill_gain is fetched from config
gathering_skill_gain = SkillGainAmount(SkillValue, RedLevel + 25, gathering_skill_gain);

// same file, Player::UpdateCraftSkill, after craft_skill_gain is fetched from config
craft_skill_gain = SkillGainAmount(SkillValue, _spell_idx->second->TrivialSkillLineRankLow, craft_skill_gain);

// The function to compute multiplier (2 is arbitrary here)
inline uint32 SkillGainAmount(uint32 SkillValue, uint32 YellowLevel, uint32 SkillMultiplier)
{
    if (SkillValue <= YellowLevel) {
        return 2 * SkillMultiplier;
    }
    return SkillMultiplier;
}
```

But due to updates to the core it's become tedious to stash changes, update to the latest commit and unstash changes. I would like to port this to a module, but I did not find anything related to that in `ScriptMgr`, `PlayerScript` (only something fishing related, which does not necessarily help. How do I accomplish that? Do I need to create a new hook?